# How to make nodejs code from curl messenger bot

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm currently make bot for messenger. I read the docs and there are curl, I still don't understand how to make it work in my server. I'm using node js as server and deploy my code in Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a package like request (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to make HTTP calls (communicate) to the Facebook Graph API or build your entire bot using a framework like BootBot (https://github.com/Charca/bootbot). BootBot makes it rather easy to create and deploy a Facebook Messenger bot using nodejs.

Comment: Thank's for the answer, it helps me a lot!